# Can we do orders.stream().mapToInt(Order::getQuantity).sum()) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In java I'm using streams to calculate the sum of a list of orders like this:

```
orders.stream().mapToInt(Order::getQuantity).sum()
```

I'm wondering whether there is an equally elegant way to do this in javascript when iterating over an array of Order instances.  Essentially an array like this:

```
[{quantity: 10}, {quantity: 20}, {quantity: 15}, ...]
```

I have something like this so far, but I'm wondering if it could be even shorter:

```
  orders.map((order)=>order.quantity).reduce((a, b)=> a+b,0);
```

Comment: Yes, just look at the api of `Array`. There's `map`, `reduce`, etc that can achieve similar results.

Comment: You edited your question to add a use of the `Arrays` calls and I think that mostly covers it. These calls provide the basic building blocks but are not as rich (or efficient) as the Java streams api.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to use `map` just do:

```
orders.reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0));
```

```js
console.log([{
  quantity: 10
}, {
  quantity: 20
}, {
  quantity: 15
}].reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0));
```

Comment: Hah. There should be a 'make your code cleverer and less readable with `reduce`' FAQ somewhere.

Comment: When using `reduce()` method, one should know that, like it name implies, it will reduce your array into a single value. `accumulator + currentValue[property]` with an `initialValue` of `0`. It's quite readable to me `:P`.

Comment: I think it's kind of terrible for readability. Of course, in practice, if you write js, you'll get familiar with `reduce` idioms. The comment was mostly tongue-in-cheek, though. I suppose you could init a local var and `forEach` it, as well.

Comment: Of course readability is important, maybe something like `orders.reduce((sum, order) => sum + order.quantity, 0));` would do the trick. The code can just be obfuscated afterwards.

Comment: Awesome - I like the readability factor for the last version a lot - all great comments overall!